# AWS Connect - Outbound call returns a 200 but phone call isn't being made

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a very basic flow whereby I want to programmatically make a phone call to a customer with a text to voice message like "Your 2FA code is 123456"

```
    var request = new StartOutboundVoiceContactRequest
    {
        ContactFlowId = contactFlowId,
        DestinationPhoneNumber = destinationPhoneNumber,
        SourcePhoneNumber = sourcePhoneNumber,
        InstanceId = "INSTANCE-ID"
    };

    var response = await connectClient.StartOutboundVoiceContactAsync(request);

    // Check the response for success or additional processing.
    if (response.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        // Contact flow successfully initiated.
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle errors or failure cases.
    }
```

[image]

When I run the code.... a response of 200 is returned.

BUT the destination phone number (my mobile) never rang.

I do note that I am using a toll free number as opposed to a DID one as the source number could that be the root cause?

Comment: Are you using the phone number associated with the Amazon Connect instance, in E.164 format as a source phone number?

Comment: Yes... source number is +611800999999 where 9 is the correct number we've been assigned

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hmm, sounds tricky. I've run into similar issues with Amazon Connect before. Let's see if we can figure this out:

1. **Instance Settings:** First, double-check if you've enabled `Outbound calling` on your Amazon Connect instance.
2. **Contact Flows:** Have a look at the contact flow you're using. Make sure it's set up correctly for outbound calls.
3. **Phone Number Format:** Make sure your `destinationPhoneNumber` is in the right format, like `+12065551234`. And yeah, try using a DID instead of a toll-free number as the source. Sometimes toll-free numbers can be finicky with outbound calls.
4. **Logs:** Dive into the CloudWatch Logs for your Connect instance. They can often provide hints on what's going wrong.
5. **Service Limits:** Just a thought, but you might want to check if you've hit any service limits on concurrent calls.
6. **Region:** It's a small thing, but ensure you're in the correct AWS region for your Connect instance.
7. **Billing:** I've been caught out before by AWS billing issues that paused some services. Maybe check that everything's okay on that front.
8. **Permissions:** Make sure the IAM role you're using has the right permissions for the task.

If all else fails, you might want to try making an outbound call manually in the Amazon Connect interface. If that doesn't work either, it might be a deeper issue with your Connect setup.

Hope that helps! If you're still stuck, maybe reach out to AWS Support. They've been pretty helpful in my experience.

Best of luck with your project!